# How to inject a nestjs service into another service when both belong to the same module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dependency-injection, nestjs

I have the following scenario in NestJS:

```
// user.service.ts
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  constructor(
    private readonly userRepository: UserRepository,
    private readonly userProfileService: UserProfileService,
  ) {}
}


// user-profile.service.ts
@Injectable()
export class UserProfileService {
  constructor(
    private readonly userProfileRepository: UserProfileRepository,
  ) {}
}


// user.module.ts
@Module({
imports: [DataRepositoryModule], // Required for the repository dependencies
  providers: [UserService, UserProfileService],
  exports: [UserService, UserProfileService],
})
export class UserModule {}
```

However, when I try to use the UserService inside a controller from another module, I get the following error:

```
Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UserService (UserRepository, ?). Please make sure that the argument dependency at index [1] is available in the UserModule context.
Potential solutions:    
- If dependency is a provider, is it part of the current UserModule?
- If dependency is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within UserModule?
@Module({
        imports: [ /* the Module containing dependency */ ]
      })
```

Controller code:

```
@Controller()
export class UserController {
  constructor(private readonly userService: UserService) {}
}
```

Controller module:

```
@Module({
  imports: [],
  providers: [],
  controllers: [UserController],
})
export class UserManagementModule {}
```

Main app.module.ts:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    UserManagementModule,
    UserModule,
    DataRepositoryModule.forRoot(),
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I'm confused because I'm doing exactly what the error suggests, adding both services inside the providers array (UserModule). What could I be missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your error, it looks like there's a circular dependency between your file imports. Check to make sure that you don't have a circular import chain going on (i.e. ServiceA imports ServiceB imports ServiceA or ServiceA imports ModuleA imports ServiceB imports ServiceA). This can especially become common common when using barrel files inside the same module.

Comment: Thank you, in this case the issue was solved by removing barrel files for any provider. There is a warning in the official NestJS documentation where they don't recommend using them that way: https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/circular-dependency
I think the error message is misleading though, it made me lose a lot of time.

Comment: There's two types of circular dependencies. Circular file imports (file A imports file B imports file A). Nest can't easily detect these, because tokens can come in as `undefined` so Nest just calls it `dependency`. The other is an injection dependency (service A injects service B injects service A). These Nest **can** detect and gives the error (most of the time) shown in the docs